# ODBC Driver Connect auto fill

Tags: ms-access, odbc, database-connection, driver, autofill

I have an Access Database connected (linked table) to an Oracle database.
I wrote some Select queries. Every time I run it, I get an "Oracle ODBC Driver Connect" input box.
Is there a way to write a VBA macro to enter the username and password (auto fill) and Enter Ok?
I'm trying to set up an auto run for macros in this Access db.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you linked the tables (assuming you did), did you save the password? -- Is the query an Access query using linked tables, or a Pass-Through query?

Comment: You can in code execute a separate logon before you touch or use any linked table. However, before I post such code,  you still going to have this prompt + logon issue for the general application. As a result, you should thus re-link the tables and check the save password issue else this issue will persist not only for your VBA code  you are trying to run, but will occur for the general application.

Comment: @Andre I create a DSN referring to Oracle db, to create linked table. No i didn't save the password anywhere, I don't remember getting an option to save it. Yes, query that i am running is a select query, selecting records from the linked table.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, sorry i couldn't understand.

Comment: see my answer - I give an example of the logon code concept, but really, the most simple is to re-link the tables and make sure you check the box to save the password.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, when you link the tables, you are given an option to save the password in those table links. If you missed this step, then you will get that ODBC prompt.

THIS HAS ZERO to do with you writing select queries. The simple matter is try clicking on one of the linked tables you use in such quires. Either you get an ODBC prompt or you do not.

If you do, then of course you going to get such a prompt when you write a query. YOU WANT to FIRST get the table links working without an ODBC prompt and THEN write those queries based on the linked tables.

So get the linked tables working first. Forget about and don’t’ worry about your queries you are writing. Until such time that a simple click on (opening) a linked table works and does not throw out the ODBC prompt, then you are looking at the WRONG problem.

Once you get your linked tables working without a prompt, then your queries will also work without a prompt.

So you have two choices to fix this problem.

Simple re-link your tables, and ensure that you select [x] check box during re-link to save the password.

The prompt you missed and want to select is this one:

[image]

Now if your tables are already linked and you run the linked table manger, you WILL NOT get this prompt anymore. So you have to delete the table links, and re-create.

Of course deleting the table links can often result in the linked table names being changed, and that can be a pain, especially if you have a LOT of linked tables. Only you can make this judgement call as to what is less work. If you have just a few tables, then just delete them, and use the external data -> then in the import and link secton, choose ODBC and you can add the tables, but REMEMBER to select (check) the above save password box as per above that you missed.

Now, most people over time wind up with some table re-link code VBA. So if you have suc re-link code already working and handy, then simply re-run that code with the user/password included in the connection string you use in that code. Of course if you don't have such code, then the above linked table manager in Access is a code free solution and is obviously your best choice and course of action.

So in place of above, you can find some table re-link code that will force (save) the user/id in the table links for you.

However, if you don’t want to delete + re-create all those tables, and you don’t have already setup some re-link code, there is also another (3rd) choice.

In your application start-up code simple execute a one-time logon. If you do this, then the ODBC prompt will not appear when you use the linked tables and hence also not appear when you attempt to run/build/use a query based on those linked tables.

The code to execute a one-time logon will look like this:

```
Function TestLogin(strCon As String) As Boolean

  On Error GoTo TestError

  Dim dbs          As DAO.Database
  Dim qdf          As DAO.QueryDef

  Set dbs = CurrentDb()
  Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("")

   qdf.connect = strCon

   qdf.ReturnsRecords = False

   'Any VALID SQL statement that runs on server will work below.
   ' this does assume user has enough rights to query built in
   ' system tables

   qdf.sql = "SELECT 1 "
   qdf.Execute

   TestLogin = True

   Exit Function

TestError:
   TestLogin = False
   Exit Function

End Function
```

Above code run ONE time on start-up of your application will thus eliminate the ODBC prompt(s) when you click on a linked table. And of course once that issue of linked tables is resolved, then of course creating or clicking on your query or running those quires will now ALSO work without the prompts.

You can NOT auto fill that prompt, you have to take CORRECT steps in the first place to PREVENT that prompt from appearing. So to answer your question?

No, you can't write code to enter the requested prompt, but if you link your tables with the password saved, or execute the above logon code, the prompt will NOT appear in the first place.